# Есть ли библиотека для подсчета выражений?

Tags: java

Есть ли библиотека, которые читает строку и считает выражение, записанное в ней? Например: ((2+6)Х8)/2

Comment: На Java, если не ошибаюсь нет, но вы можете написать свой расчет с помощью древовидной структуры(с помощью паттерна композит, где узел может быть, как знак, так и число). Там не так сложно. Если будет сложно дерево, то можете использовать обратную польскую запись.

Comment: Как вариант, используйте BeanShell.
Дубликат вопроса [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/how-to-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать для этого [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) `bsh.Interpreter`:

```
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
interpreter.eval("result = 5+4*(7-15)");
System.out.println(interpreter.get("result"));
```

При этом помните, что строка может быть из ненадежного источника, соответственно открывается проблема "инъекций кода".

---

Если вы хотите более сложный, но вместе с тем и безопасный способ, вы можете использовать [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) и компилировать/интерпретировать выражения самостоятельно.

---

Вы также можете использовать класс `ScriptEngine` и вычислять это как в JS:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
Object result = engine.eval("4*5");
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/how-to-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number/1432282)

Comment: Просьба минусующему объяснить почему он поставил "против".

Comment: Видимо это проявление токсичности ввиду ссылки на английский оверфлоу, плюсанул.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можете использовать BeanShell.
Дубликат вопроса можно найти [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/how-to-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number)